# Including multiple headers for achieving polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have an interface `ver` as

```
// ver.h
class ver
{
    public:
    virtual void func()=0;
};
```

Then `ver1` and `ver2` implement this interface. `ver1` and `ver2` differ in the sense they include header `test\header.h` and `test2\header.h`. Now `test\header.h` and `test2\header.h` are not under my control and are mostly similar except for a function pointer which is the reason for having `ver1` and `ver2`

```
// test\header.h
#ifndef header
#define header
typedef void
(*FuncPoint)(
struct_type_a
);   
#endif
```

and

```
// test2\header.h
#ifndef header
#define header
typedef void
(*FuncPoint)(
 struct_type_b
);   
#endif
```

Now the implementations

```
//ver1.h
#include "test\header.h"
class ver1:public ver
{
    public:
        FuncPoint f;
};
```

and

```
//ver2.h
#include "test2\header.h"
class ver2:public ver
{
    public:
        FuncPoint f;
};
```

and `ver1.cpp` and `ver2.cpp` will be using the respective `f`

Now the polymorphic behavior comes into play here

```
//something.cpp

#include "ver.h"
#include "ver1.h"
#include "ver2.h"
ver* somefunc()
{
    if (some_condition)
        return new ver1();
    else
        return new ver2();
}
```

Since `something.cpp` includes both `ver1.h` and `ver2.h`, first `test\header1.h` gets included and because of the include guards, `test\header2.h` is not included and hence there is no `FuncPoint` defined for `class ver2` and `something.cpp` fails to compile.
On the other hand `ver1.cpp` and `ver2.cpp` gets compiled successfully since  there is only one `header.h` included.

I could do a `#undef header` after including `ver1.h` in `something.cpp` but that would give redefinition error for other things which are same in  `test\header.h1` and `tes\header2.h`.

A simple fix would be to not have `FuncPoint f` as global variables instead of member variables, this way i won't have to include `test\header.h` in `ver1.h` but instead in `ver1.cpp`.

Is there some other better way to fix this?

EDIT:
I could forward declare `struct_type_a` and `struct_type_b` in `something.cpp` and avoid including `ver1.h` and `ver2.h` in `something.cpp`. But class `ver1` and `ver2` use other things(to declare members) from `test\header.h` as well(which are same in both versions).

Comment: This may not be the solution to your problem, but generally, either I use `#pragma once` instead of header guards or I use *longer names* in the header guards, like `INCLUDES_TEST2_HEADER` and `INCLUDES_TEST_HEADER`.

Comment: Feel like something to PIMPL, so that headers are included in cpp files.

Comment: He said that the header files are not under his control, so he can't rename the header guards nor change the guards into `#pragma once`

Comment: @doctorlove the issue boils down to both `test\header.h` and `test2\header` getting included in `something.cpp`. But `something.cpp` needs `ver1` and `ver2` definitions which in turn need `FuncPointer`. I think the only option available is using globals instead of members.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include `header.h` in `ver1.h` or `ver2.h` but in the respective .cpp files: `FuncPoint` is a pointer so you can use forward declarations. Since `ver1.h` and `ver2.h` will both be included you will need to rename it however where exposed (in the .cpp files you will be able to use the original `FuncPoint` too, since you include only one definition of it there):

```
//ver1.h
#include "ver.h"
struct struct_type_a;
typedef void (*FuncPoint_a)(struct_type_a); 
class ver1 : public ver
{
    public:
        FuncPoint_a f;
        static ver1 *create();
};
```

Also the creation of the polymorphic objects must be demanded to methods implemented in the .cpp files, in the `create()` static method.

Following your code it would become:

```
//something.cpp
#include "ver.h"    
#include "ver1.h"
#include "ver2.h"
ver* somefunc()
{
    if (some_condition)
        return ver1::create();
    else
        return ver2::create();
}
```

In this way the two colliding headers will never be included in the same file.

I've added the inclusion of `ver.h` in `ver1.h` (and `ver2.h`) because this is the source using it. Including it in `something.cpp` only is not correct (ver1 and ver2 need it) - but not related to the current problem.

Comment: This looks good but i have to give typedef's and types(which are same in both) for other stuff of `header.h` as well which are members of `ver1` and `ver2`.

Comment: following your question you have to insert the forward declaration of `struct_type_a` in `ver1.h` and of `struct_type_b` in `ver2.h`. In order to avoid collision you can call them `FuncPoint_a` and `FuncPoint_b` to avoid collision in the typedefs

Comment: I've edited the answer too. In fact it was not working before - but still untested.